# SSIS calling a WCF for each record parallel processing possible?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, ssis

I have a flat file with about a million records. What my SSIS does currently is take one record at a time, debatch it, map parameters to a wcf service request based on certain business rules, call the service, write the response back to the DB.

The service call takes 1 sec for each call. So I am looking at about 276 hours. If I process one record at a time [if I am not mistaken].

I have multiple web servers to handle my wcf request, so that is not a problem. So within a second I would be able to process 4-6 wcf requests.

What can I do to improve it?

Comment: You could use a script to split your file into smaller files and then run parallel execution paths to process the smaller files simultaneously.

Comment: How are you "debatching" it? If it's a Data Flow with a flat file reader, yes, we've got a handy tool for you. That said, even if you can handle 6 at one time, aren't you still looking at 46 hours?

Comment: @billinkc thanks, its a dataflow task yes. 46 hours is okay, we will run it nightly for a week.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Balanced Data Distributor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4123), which is part of SSIS.
It takes one input (your source file) and splits it across as many outputs as you add to it.

Each output would link to a component to call you service.

See the excellent write up from the SQL Server Performance Team [The “Balanced Data Distributor” for SSIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlperf/archive/2011/05/25/the-balanced-data-distributor-for-ssis.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I live in an environment that does not support add-ins. I am still on SQL/SSIS 2008.

Comment: BDD is a Microsoft supported add-in, it was simply released out of band. And it's the solution you want. It's designed specifically for laggy destinations. I usually see it with people pushing data into CRM but your use case is equally applicable